Covariance estimation via bootstrap
Given two samples : an i.i.d. $n_u$-sample $(u_{j})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u}$ and an i.i.d. $n_v$-sample $(v_{i})_{1 \leq i \leq n_v}$.
Note : The populations of the two samples are disjoint (let's say we choose price of bananas for $u$ and the prices of oranges for $v$). These samples are not necessarily drawn independently in the sense that the draw of some units $u_i$ can be linked with the draw of some units $v_j$ (maybe we chose some bananas and oranges in the same market).
We can create an estimator of the means of these two samples, respectively $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{v}$.
The goal here is to estimate the covariance of $\bar{u}$ and $\bar{v}$ (I suppose that the non-indenpendancy of the draws of the two samples can cause the covariance to be non-zero, so I want to estimate the covariance).
My idea
So my idea is to create bootstrap re-samples of $(u_{j})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u}$ and $(v_{i})_{1 \leq i \leq n_v}$ we could write $\left\{ (u_{j}^{*(b)})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u}, (v_{i}^{*(b)}))_{1 \leq i \leq n_v} \right\}_{b=1}^B$. And with that we can have the means $u^{*(b)}=\frac{1}{n_u - 1} \sum_{j \in b} u_{j}^{*(b)}$ and the same goes for $v^{*(b)}$.
Thus, I think an estimator of $\text{Cov}(\bar{u}_{n_u},\bar{v}_{n_v})$ can be :
$$
\frac{1}{B-1} \sum_{b=1}^B (u^{*(b)} - \bar{u}^{*})(v^{*(b)} - \bar{v}^{*}).
$$
However I fail to prove that this estimator truly estimate the covariance. I wrote that if we consider the conditional expectation (I write $\mathbb{E}^*\left[ . \right] = \mathbb{E}\left[ .|(u_{j})_{1 \leq j \leq n_u}, (v_{i})_{1 \leq i \leq n_u}\right]$) :
$$
\mathbb{E}^*\left[ (u^{*(b)} - \bar{u}^{*})(v^{*(b)} - \bar{v}^{*})\right] = \frac{1}{(n_u - 1)(n_v - 1)} \sum_{i \in b}\sum_{j \in b} \mathbb{E}^*\left[ (u_{j}^{*(b)} - \bar{u}^{*})(v_{j}^{*(b)} - \bar{v}^{*})\right] = 0
$$
because the draw on the $u_i$ and the draw of the $v_j$ are independant in our bootstrap re-samples.
I think that this is due to the fact we draw independantly our two re-samples when the two samples are not independant, however how to make sure our re-sample draw can be as if it was the one from the samples ?
